# Not getting "potentially dangerous request" error

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, sitefinity

For an ASP.NET MVC 4 website hosted by SiteFinity, I can enter in a text box this text:

`< input type="text" >`

It passes the values to the MVC back-end with no issues.  I was expecting to see the ["potentially dangerous request" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81991/2258) but I am not getting it.

The only attributes on the action on the controller back end are:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

I don't have `[AllowHTML]`
I tried adding in `[ValidateInput(true)]` but it didn't do anything.

I have checked in my filterconfig file but that is just adding the `[Authorize]` attribute.

I have checked the web.config and the httpRuntime settings are here

```
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" 
        maxUrlLength="102400" 
        maxQueryStringLength="10000"
     requestValidationType="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Claims.CustomRequestValidator, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
```

It doesn't have `requestValidationMode="2.0"` set and don't have `validateRequest="false"` set.  I don't know what that Sitefinity CustomRequest Validator does, was a part of updating to Sitefinity 6.0 and is suspicious, but I have that setting set on prod and I do get the potentially dangerous errors.

I'm only finding pages telling me how to avoid getting this error.  Anyone have an idea how I enable it?  Any ideas on what else may be in the code that is disabling it?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned in the question.  This is a jQuery Mobile front end using Razor with a MVC 4 back end using Sitefinity as the Content Manager.  Wanted to put in all the tags as right now I'm not sure if one of these technologies, or a conflict between these technologies, is causing the problem instead of just a stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: Please don't tag with things that aren't part of the question (tag-spam).  Feel free to add the additional relevant parts to the question and then retag.  However, I doubt that your client-side technologies, [tag:jquery-validate] or [tag:jquery-mobile], would have anything to do with your server side validation.